# Highcharts not "graphing" in Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm having an odd problem where my Highcharts graph is only properly "graphing" on Chrome.  The graph frame itself shows up just fine (the axis' names, labels, white background, etc), but the actual columns do not get animated, nor do they show up on the graph to represent the actual data.  It just appears to look like an empty graph.

The data is being called via AJAX. Everything on that end is fine.  The code itself is also very simple, so not sure what could be causing this. Here is the code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Highcharts.chart('modal-graph-wrapper', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Build Time vs. Step'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Length of Time (seconds)'
                },
                categories: timeArray
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: nameArray
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Build Time (seconds)',
                data: timeArray,
                lineWidth: 3,
                marker: {
                    radius: 3,
                    fillColor: '#337ab7'
                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out.  It is because the Date.parse function does not work as expected in Firefox or Safari; whereas in Chrome it works as anticipated.  Restructuring the time format solved my issue. Thanks!